# Java listing distinct names

Tags: java, printing, while-loop

Here i have some code for scanning a file and splitting it into items

Code =

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));

while (scanner.hasNext()) {

                    String line = scanner.nextLine();
                    String[] item = line.split(":");
```

therefore item[0] = team1
          item[1]= homegoals etc...

File.txt =

```
Chelsea : 1 : Fulham : 1
Leeds : 2 Chelsea : 1
Leeds : 1 : Fulham : 2
```

Above is the file Im reading. What code could I use to print out a scoreboard where the team names didn't duplicate. The goals, points etc don't matter I just want to the print to list the team names without them duplicating;

Chelsea

Leeds

Fulham

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) to store team names. If you try to add some value to a Set multiple times, it will be added only once and so you will have no duplicates:

```
Set<String> teamNames = new HashSet<>();

while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String[] parts = scanner.nextLine().split("\\s*:\\s*");
    teamNames.add(parts[0]);
    teamNames.add(parts[2]);
}

for (String teamName : teamNames) {
    System.out.println(teamName);
}
```

Output:

```
Fulham
Leeds
Chelsea
```

By the way, using `:` to split the String is not the best idea. In that case the team names could have leading/trailing whitespace so " Chelsea" and "Chelsea" would actually be considered different names. Instead try splitting using this (`\\s*:\\s*`), which translates to zero or more whitespace characters, colon and zero or more whitespace characters again.

Also I assume this is a typo

```
Leeds : 2 Chelsea : 1
```

and it should be

```
Leeds : 2 : Chelsea : 1
```